# A good resource on the Radon-Nikodym Property in reflexive Banach Spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, geometric-functional-analysis

I'm looking for a good resource that builds the theory of the Radon-Nikodym Property. I'm not particularly interested in the measure-theoretic characterisation; I'd like the geometry of Banach Spaces version, involving strongly exposed points of convex sets. If possible, I would also like the proofs to concentrate more a geometric approach over a convex/variational analysis approach, though this is not a deal-breaker. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chapter 5 of [Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis](https://books.google.com/books/about/Geometric_Nonlinear_Functional_Analysis.html?id=lXZ95EKwjYUC) by Benyamini and Lindenstrauss is the best geometrically-minded resource on RNP that I know.

Comment: Thank you. I have one follow-up question. I'm reading through Theorem 5.11, at the bottom of page 106. I don't understand how Baire Category Theorem is being used. Do you know which BCT is being used, and how?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.