# Are $L_p$ spaces Asplund?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $p \in [1, + \infty).$ It is well known that $L_p$ spaces are Banach spaces. However, I am wondering whether they are Asplund. What about the case $p = + \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that a space is Asplund iff its dual has the Radon-Nikodym property, and this is true (in particular) for all reflexive spaces. So, if you want to show that $L^p$ is Asplund for $p\in (1,\infty)$, then we can use that its dual is $L^q$ (with $1/p+1/q=1$), and $L^q$ is reflexive.

For some references on the RND, see [A good resource on the Radon-Nikodym Property in reflexive Banach Spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521014/a-good-resource-on-the-radon-nikodym-property-in-reflexive-banach-spaces)

and

"Geometric Aspects of Convex Sets with the Radon-Nikodým Property" by Bourgin (who also talks about Asplund spaces). I believe you can also find it (or what's needed to prove it) in Dunford and Pettis.

Comment: Is it Jean Bourgain or Richard Burgin?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thanks for the catch! Slip on my end :)

Comment: This was subtle, because it appears that Jean Bourgain also has at least one paper on this subject.